# Android Map activity not showing location on device

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geolocation, maps

I made an android app that shows the user's location using the map activity of android. It works fine on the emulator. It also worked fine on the device in the first attempt, and then subsequent attempts failed to get the location. It takes some time, after which it logs out - DpmTcmClient: Couldn't find 'tcm' socket after 120times. quit trying.

```
package com.example.showuserlocation;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    public GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    LatLng userLocation;
    float lat=0,lon=0;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        // if requestCode == 1 this is the actual way
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000,100,locationListener);
            }
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        userLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("You are here"));
        //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));

        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                mMap.clear();
                Log.i("Location",location.toString());
                lat = (float)location.getLatitude();
                lon = (float)location.getLongitude();
                userLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("You are here"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));

                Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());

                try {
                    List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);
                    if (address != null && address.size()>0) {
                        Log.i("Address",address.get(0).toString());
                        if (address.get(0).getAddressLine(0) != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, address.get(0).getAddressLine(0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.i("Info",address.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Could not extract address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.i("Error","Could not extract address");
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        }
        else {
            Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if (lastLocation != null) {
                userLocation = new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude());
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("You are here"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Your last location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Known Last Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,100000,1000,locationListener);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
2020-06-30 16:16:40.769 16169-16169/? I/howuserlocatio: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2020-06-30 16:16:40.989 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/howuserlocatio: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
2020-06-30 16:16:41.113 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2020-06-30 16:16:41.255 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/zzbz: Making Creator dynamically
2020-06-30 16:16:41.267 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Unsupported class loader
2020-06-30 16:16:41.270 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2020-06-30 16:16:41.273 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:202117000
2020-06-30 16:16:41.273 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 202117000
2020-06-30 16:16:41.273 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation V/DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
2020-06-30 16:16:41.306 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/DynamiteLoaderV2: [71] Mapsdynamite
2020-06-30 16:16:41.310 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Unsupported class loader
2020-06-30 16:16:41.312 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2020-06-30 16:16:41.374 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services client version: 12451000
2020-06-30 16:16:41.382 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 202117028
2020-06-30 16:16:41.493 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Accessing hidden field Ljava/nio/Buffer;->address:J (light greylist, reflection)
2020-06-30 16:16:41.763 16169-16212/com.example.showuserlocation D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-06-30 16:16:41.764 16169-16212/com.example.showuserlocation I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
2020-06-30 16:16:41.769 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation W/Activity: Slow Operation: Activity com.example.showuserlocation/.MapsActivity onCreate took 580ms
2020-06-30 16:16:41.820 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : c455b9b, Ib7912a5d4e
    Build Date                       : 09/16/19
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: EV031.25.03.07
    Local Branch                     : mybranche9d87587-05ad-f10c-aeb4-5cb90179c3d8
    Remote Branch                    : quic/gfx-adreno.lnx.1.0.r48-rel
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
2020-06-30 16:16:41.820 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S L 6.0.7 AArch64
2020-06-30 16:16:41.830 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation I/Adreno: PFP: 0x005ff112, ME: 0x005ff066
2020-06-30 16:16:41.835 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-06-30 16:16:41.835 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-06-30 16:16:41.836 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-06-30 16:16:41.836 16169-16238/com.example.showuserlocation D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-06-30 16:16:41.947 16169-16169/com.example.showuserlocation I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.example.showuserlocation, PackageName:com.example.showuserlocation
2020-06-30 16:16:43.766 16169-16233/com.example.showuserlocation W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
2020-06-30 16:16:43.771 16169-16233/com.example.showuserlocation I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
2020-06-30 16:16:43.771 16169-16233/com.example.showuserlocation I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
2020-06-30 16:16:43.775 16169-16233/com.example.showuserlocation I/DynamiteLoaderV2: [71] Googlecertificates
2020-06-30 16:16:43.776 16169-16233/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Unsupported class loader
2020-06-30 16:16:43.778 16169-16233/com.example.showuserlocation W/howuserlocatio: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
2020-06-30 16:16:49.153 16169-16203/com.example.showuserlocation I/howuserlocatio: ProcessProfilingInfo new_methods=811 is saved saved_to_disk=1 resolve_classes_delay=8000
2020-06-30 16:18:42.059 16169-16234/com.example.showuserlocation W/DpmTcmClient: Couldn't find 'tcm' socket after 120times. quit trying
```

Comment: Can you add what you did, so we can know from where it comes from this bug ?

Comment: Done ! I have uploaded the code and the logs.